# multiple classes called, second class doesn't work

Tags: java, class

My issue with my code is that I have a class called Student. This class computes grades from students and lists their names and grade. The second class is called CourseOffering and is used to compute the number of semesters, number of students in the class, etc. The third class is what puts it all together. On top of all this, the information is read from a .txt file. I tested my Student class and the values I got were correct and it works fine, but then I try to add the CourseOffering class methods into the equation, and i get this error...

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at CourseOffering.setNumberOfSemesters(CourseOffering.java:17)
at CourseStatistics.main(CourseStatistics.java:21)
```

The student class has the code that reads the .txt file and I won't include the rest of it because it is not important...

```
public void openFile(){
  try { //start try statement
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("gradesA5.txt"));  //initialize scanner to scan from the grades.txt file
  } //end try statement
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //start catch statement
    System.out.println("Error opening file. Please make sure that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class"); //print statement telling user that the grades.txt file is not in the right place
    System.exit(0); //system exit 
  } //end catch statement
}
```

CourseOffering class...

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CourseOffering {

private Scanner scanner;

//initialize data members
private int students;
private String description;

private int numberOfSemesters;
int studentArrayCount = 0;

public void setNumberOfSemesters(){
    if(scanner.hasNext()){
        numberOfSemesters = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

public int getNumberOfSemesters(){
    return numberOfSemesters;
}

public void setStudents(){
    int[] student = new int[numberOfSemesters];
    student[studentArrayCount] = scanner.nextInt();
    students = student[studentArrayCount];
    studentArrayCount++;
}

public void computeHomeworkAverage(){

}

public void computeTestAverage(){

}

public void countPassingStudents(){

}
 }
```

And finally the class that calls the methods...

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CourseStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Student myStudent = new Student();

    CourseOffering myCourse = new CourseOffering();


    myStudent.openFile();

    myCourse.setNumberOfSemesters();

    myStudent.testing();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    myStudent.setfirstName();

    myStudent.setLastName();

    myStudent.setAssignmentScore();

    myStudent.setLabScore();

    myStudent.setMidterm1Score();

    myStudent.setMidterm2Score();

    myStudent.setFinalExamScore();

    myStudent.setQuizScore();

    myStudent.setAttendanceScore();

    myStudent.setPATScore();

    myStudent.setZyanteScore();

    myStudent.computeLetterGrade();

    System.out.println(myStudent.getFirstName() + " " + myStudent.getLastName() + " " + myStudent.computeTotalHomeworkScore() + " " + myStudent.computeTotalTestScore() + "      " + myStudent.getLetterGrade());
    }
    System.out.println(myCourse.getNumberOfSemesters());
}   
 }
```

basically i need to know how to call the CourseOffering class that also is suppose to be reading from the .txt file read from the Student class, while not getting an error. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to use a `Debugger`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you dont have

```
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

anywhere in your code, meaning it is null when you try to use it.

**EDIT:** I Just looked at that non-code blocked piece of code you had (and fixed it for you), and saw that you do infact create a new Scanner object in that class. However, the scanner in the CourseOffering class is not the same one, and is still null.

You will probably have to pass the scanner object you create in student into CourseOffering in order to use it there, or better yet create it in the main method and pass it into both.

**EDIT2:**

You will have to pass it in as a value in the constructor. So consider the following class:

```
class Human{

  int height;//in cm

  public Human(int inputHeight){
    height = inputHeight;
  }

}
```

Then when you create it -

```
Human h = new Human(190);
```

Then the height value of h will be 190.

The same concept works with passing in objects like your scanner, where once you set it correctly, it will be available inside your new objects.

Comment: to add on: `scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`;

Comment: ok, sorry if i sound like a noob (cause i am) but how do i pass the student class scanner object to the courseoffering class.

Comment: okay, so are we talking about passing the code: privateScanner scanner, or are we talking about passing the part of the code that is inside of the openfile method?

Comment: It would be better to have the openFile code in the main method and pass the scanner into both objects. However if you want to create the scanner inside Student, then to get that scanner from outside Student, you need to either make it public or write a getter method, then if you create the Student first, you can do myCourse = new CourseOffering(student.getScanner())

Comment: You said it would be better the have the openFile code in the main method...That does sound easier, but i don't understand how to pass the scanner into both objects (by objects do you mean my two other classes?)

Comment: Once you create your scanner, you will need to pass it into your Student and CourseOffering in the same way that I passed 190 into Human. Sorry, but I dont want to just straight up give you the answer :P

Comment: Alright, i just can't seem to wrap my head around this. Is there a youtube video that explains how to do this that you could direct me to? Your help was great! But i think i need to see it in action and learn how to do this.

Comment: To be honest, this is among core concepts of the language, so any simple java tutorial regarding objects should do.

Comment: Nah its no problem! infact i edited that bit out of my comment. If you have further problems you can't seem to figure out don't hesitate to raise more questions.

Comment: public CourseOffering(Scanner myStudent.getScanner){
  scanner = myStudent.getScanner;
 } ...my constructor, followed by the calling part: CourseOffering myCourse = new CourseOffering(myStudent.getScanner()); ...i get the same error so i obviously did it wrong, but am i close?

Comment: your CourseOffering constructor should look like this: public CourseOffering(Scanner inScanner){ scanner = inScanner; }
And your getScanner() method in studednt like this: public Scanner getScanner(){ return scanner; }

Comment: Okay, that got rid of the errors when trying to scan from the CourseOffering class...my only problem now is that when the CourseOffering class starts scanning, it goes back to the first data member in the .txt file instead of continuing from where the other one left off...how do i fix this?